# Query com calculo retornando erro na condição

Tags: mysql

Tenho o seguinte select:

```
SELECT  
  imp_loja       AS LOJA,
  imp_item       AS ITEM,
  imp_desc       AS DESCRICAO,
  imp_dias_giro  AS DIAS_DE_GIRO,
  imp_nec        AS NECESSIDADE,
  imp_pedido     AS PEDIDO,
  imp_bancao     AS BANCAO,
  imp_romaneio   AS ROMANEIO, 
  imp_transito   AS TRANSITO,
  imp_gondula    AS GONDULA,
  imp_fator      AS FATOR,
  imp_reposicao  AS REPOSICAO,
  imp_estoque    AS ESTOQUE,
  (imp_nec - imp_fator) AS NEC_FAT,
  (imp_estoque / imp_fator) AS EXT_X_FATOR,
  (imp_estoque + imp_transito)ESTTRAN,
  imp_data       AS DATA
  FROM importacao WHERE ESTTRAN < 0 ORDER BY imp_desc
```

Estou querendo mostrar somente os que estiverem com o saldo negativo, só que esta dando erro na condição, o que poderia ser ?

> SQL execution error #1054. Resonse from the database:  Unknown column
>   'ESTTRAN' in 'where cluase'

Comment: vc não pode usar o alias, nesse caso precisa fazer o calculo novamente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você quiser usar o ALIAS você pode utilizar o `HAVING`. 
A lógica dele é a mesma do `WHERE`.

Ficando assim:

```
SELECT  
  imp_loja       AS LOJA,
  imp_item       AS ITEM,
  imp_desc       AS DESCRICAO,
  imp_dias_giro  AS DIAS_DE_GIRO,
  imp_nec        AS NECESSIDADE,
  imp_pedido     AS PEDIDO,
  imp_bancao     AS BANCAO,
  imp_romaneio   AS ROMANEIO, 
  imp_transito   AS TRANSITO,
  imp_gondula    AS GONDULA,
  imp_fator      AS FATOR,
  imp_reposicao  AS REPOSICAO,
  imp_estoque    AS ESTOQUE,
  (imp_nec - imp_fator) AS NEC_FAT,
  (imp_estoque / imp_fator) AS EXT_X_FATOR,
  (imp_estoque + imp_transito) AS ESTTRAN,
  imp_data       AS DATA
FROM importacao HAVING ESTTRAN < 0 ORDER BY imp_desc
```

Comment: perfeito,era isso mesmo.

Answer (score 3):

Você está usando o `alias` da coluna no **WHERE**. O banco não reconhece essa coluna, no caso `ESTTRAN`. Altere sua ***query*** para isso:

```
SELECT  
  imp_loja       AS LOJA,
  imp_item       AS ITEM,
  imp_desc       AS DESCRICAO,
  imp_dias_giro  AS DIAS_DE_GIRO,
  imp_nec        AS NECESSIDADE,
  imp_pedido     AS PEDIDO,
  imp_bancao     AS BANCAO,
  imp_romaneio   AS ROMANEIO, 
  imp_transito   AS TRANSITO,
  imp_gondula    AS GONDULA,
  imp_fator      AS FATOR,
  imp_reposicao  AS REPOSICAO,
  imp_estoque    AS ESTOQUE,
  (imp_nec - imp_fator) AS NEC_FAT,
  (imp_estoque / imp_fator) AS EXT_X_FATOR,
  (imp_estoque + imp_transito) AS ESTTRAN,
  imp_data       AS DATA
FROM importacao WHERE (imp_estoque + imp_transito) < 0 ORDER BY imp_desc
```

Veja que no **WHERE** a **fórmula** da sua coluna é utilizada, e não mais o `alias`.